# How does WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated check if you're logged in or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is probably a stupid question, but I've looked pretty hard on Google and couldn't come up with the answer.

I'm creating a website where the database is in another continent, so speed is a crucial issue.

From what I understand,

```
 WebSecurity.Login(form.userName, form.password))
```

initially checks the database it's initially set up with and logs you in if the username and pw are correct.

Now for every backend function I'm writing, I'm sticking a

```
[Authorize]
```

attribute and a

```
if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
{ .... }
```

before performing any action.  So does the WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated check the database at all to check if it is logged in or not?  I just need to know for speed reasons.

Also is it redundant to put the [Authorize] and WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated in EVERY backend method?

Thanks for any help and opinions

Comment: I believe it only checks wether the client has an authentication cookie set.

Comment: @HaukurHaf ah perfect i guess that's all i need to know outside the other redundancy question i have as far as using that combined with the [Authorize] attribute

Comment: Yeah, at least that's how it worked in older implementations like the Membership functionality in .NET 2 i believe.  I would also think that it's redundant to both decorate methods with the [Authorize] attribute *and* check using WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated.

Comment: `[Authorize]` is an action filter, and has no effect when applied to methods that aren't actions.

Comment: @HaukurHaf okay great thanks for your answer really appreciate it.  I guess I'll wait to see what others think

Comment: @SLaks all my backend functions are JsonResult as I'm using ASP.NET MVC in conjunction with Angular.  So that is an action filter right?  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  Still learning

Comment: What are you calling a "backend function"?

Comment: @SLaks anything that returns information.. all of them return a JsonResult type

Comment: By "back end function" do you mean web api or mvc controller actions?

Comment: @BenRobinson I believe JsonResult is a Controller action?  Similar to ActionResult

Comment: JsonResult is a return type of an mvc controller action, which is the name for routable methods onban mvc controller, if this is what you mean by "back end functions" then just applying the Authorise attribute will be sufficient.

Comment: @BenRobinson thank you!!

Comment: @HaukurHaf: not necessarily a cookie, this depends on what actual autentication scheme is used. In case of `Windows` authentication, there are no authentication cookies, there are ntlm/kerberos headers.

Comment: Good point.  I had my mind on forms authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So does the WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated check the database at all to check if it is logged in or not?

No, it just checks if the principal object in current request has the authentication flag set to true.

Usually the principal object is set by an authentication module, there are few different modules. Most use cookies to persist the information of the authenticated user (e.g. `Forms`, `SessionAuthentication`) and if the cookie is present and it's valid, the module sets the principal for the request which you can get by calling:

```
HttpContext.Current.User
```

in any method of your code (assuming the call is made from a web app that sets the `HttpContext.Current`).

Some authentication modules can rely on other authentication factors, for example the `Windows` authentication relies on NTLM/Kerberos protocols which in turn rely on specific headers rather than cookies.

> Also is it redundant to put the [Authorize] and WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated in EVERY backend method

Yes and no.

What you most probably mean by "every backend method" is you mean a controller/action method in an MVC app. If this is so then, **yes**, you don't have to repeat both in a controller/action method.

But in any other method in your backend that is not a controller/action, the `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` still works while the `Action` attribute doesn't.

Thus, if by "every method" you literally mean **every** possible method, then the answer is **no**, these two are not redundant. One works always, the other - only in MVC controllers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Wiktor Zychla has said, it is useful to note that `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` is functionally identical to `Request.IsAuthenticated`; to be precise, it's a wrapper:

```
namespace WebMatrix.WebData
{
    //other class content omitted for brevity
    public static class WebSecurity
    {

        //Context
        internal static HttpContextBase Context
        {
            get { return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current); }
        }

        //Request
        internal static HttpRequestBase Request
        {
            get { return Context.Request; }
        }

        //WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated 
        public static bool IsAuthenticated
        {
            get {  return Request.IsAuthenticated; }
        }

    }
}
```

So if you put all of the above together, `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` is equal to `HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current).Request.IsAuthenticated` under the hood.

Aside: As correctly stated in the other answers and comments, `[Authorize]` is used to specify access to controller and action methods:

> Specifies that access to a controller or action method is restricted to users who meet the authorization requirement. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx))

So `IsAuthenticated` works on both action methods and non-action methods, while `[Authorize]` only works on controllers and action methods, making it indeed redundant to use both on action methods.